# jenkinsfile executed on master agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am starting to work with jenkinsfiles.
 The jenkinsfile contains an echo message (i.e. Hello world)
This is my case:
I have jenkins (ver 2.190.1) installed on a pc with s.o. windows (master agent).
My slave agent is a pc with s.o. linux.
I put my jenkinsfile in my scm.
I have successfully configured the pipeline to run the jenkinsfile. Which is done successfully.
Jenkins makes repository checkout on *master agent* and not on *slave agent* (what I want) and *option "Lightweight checkout"* is checked.
I want this behaviour because my pipeline must to work on slave agent. And I don't want my repoository on master agent.
I searched on the net for a possible solution but without results.

Could you give me a suggestion on how to checkout my repository directly on the slave agent?

Comment: So do you want to run your complete pipeline on slave agent?

Comment: Hi Nisarg, but I'm not clear in my request. Before execute jenkinsfile, I want perform checkout on Slave agent, and execute jenkinsfile contained in it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done this way. From the below example just replace `agentLabelName` to your agent name.

**Scripted Pipeline**

```
node('agentLabelName') {
    stage('stageName') {
        echo "${env.WORKSPACE}"
        //checkout scm // If Jenkinsfile availabe with your SCM
        git url: 'https://github.com/samitkumarpatel/test0.git', branch: 'main'
    }
}
```

Declarative Pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'agentLabelName'
    }
    stages {
        stage('stageName') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello World"
                echo "${env.WORKSPACE}"
                //checkout scm // If Jenkinsfile availabe with your SCM
                git url: 'https://github.com/samitkumarpatel/test0.git', branch: 'main'
            }
        }
    }
}
```